# How to implement search from script PHP

Tags: php, csv, cmd

I have this CSV file

```
1,John,Smith,10/01/2001;
2,Brian,Green,27/12/1970;
3,Kevin,White,16/04/1997;
```

and I have this php code that prints the whole file

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Now, i need to implement a search inline the php script, so if i type something like this

```
php search.php ./file.csv 2 White
```

the output would be like this

```
3,Kevin,White,16/04/1997;
```

I am really clueless on how to do this. I'm searching from guide to guide, spent hours and I'm still clueless :( I'm new to coding, sorry if this may be a dumb question. Ty anyone who responds.

Comment: Well `fgetcsv` got you an array of the columns of one row, so now you have to search inside each single array element ... Loop over them, and check if you find a match. (You weren't specific as to whether you want to find only full matches, or partial ones as well - how exactly you check for a "match", would depend on that.)

Comment: What was the `2` in your command line example supposed to be for? Does that mean, you only wanted to search in the 2nd column? Then you don't need to loop over all array elements of course, but can access the desired one via index directly.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, the 2 indicates the coloumn

Comment: The fact is that i don't know how to link the variables of the command to the code

Comment: How to access the arguments passed in the CLI invocation of the script, you mean? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.